# Will ASUS PCI-SC200 work with Ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility, asus

I have a few piece of hardware from an early Paleozoic period that I am trying to get to work on Ubuntu. Namely a DDS1 tape drive with SCSI1 interface. I need to pick up a SCSI1 or SCSI2 adapter with PCI interface that will work under Ubuntu. Currently considering ASUS PCI-SC200, but can't quite figure out if it will work ok under Ubuntu(10.10).

If you have experience hooking up this SCSI2 adapter to a Ubuntu machine would really appreciate an advice if it's a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer to this is yes :) Bought it, tested it. It works perfectly well... which I can't say about my tape drive that chewed the tape :( Oh well...